# json data from jquery ajax to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my ajax

```
$.ajax({
    data: {id: 1,status: 1},
    success: function(data){
    Collection.success_res();
    },
    error: function(data){
    Collection.error_res();
    }
})
```

Here is my conroller

```
def update_status
    @post = Post.find params[:id]
    if @post.update_attributes params[:status]
      respond_to do |format|
      end
    end

  end
```

I am getting error as

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "1":String
```

Answer (score 0):

The $.ajax call does not look complete, moreover the field name should be in quotes in JSON. Try :

```
var mydata = {"id": 1,"status": 1}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "your post URL goes here",
    data: mydata,
    success: function (data) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert("something went wrong");
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok that is clear but i am facing error with `Couldn't find Post without an ID`. But I am passing my id right?